# Codenvy.com c++ syntax-highlighted

Tags: c++, ide, syntax-highlighting, codenvy

I'm using codenvy.com for a c++ project and it works great. My problem is h files  are not syntax-highlighted. How can I change setting to get nicely highlighted h files?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the ".h" to ".hpp" or ".hh". Some people like to distinguish between C headers (.h) and CPP headers (.hpp/.hh).

Comment: Initially I thought that this didn't answer the question, but a google for 'codenvy header' indicates that codenvy has an issue with .h headers https://github.com/codenvy/codenvy/issues/1980

Comment: @PaulFloyd Thanks, That is healpfull.